# Ansible "apt" puts unwanted second repository into sources list

Tags: ansible

On Linux Mint 21 I am trying to install signed packages from external repos.
I have the same problem with 5 different repos.

I can get the PGP key and add the repo to the **/etc/apt/sources.list.d/** directory, but when I call **apt**, it makes another entry in the sources directory (but without the pointer to the key).
This causes the install to fail.

If I remove the second entry, then the package installs correctly.
I have tried several of the parameters to apt, but without success.

Here is an example, to install **Chrome**:

```
 - name: Add Chrome signing key
   get_url:
     url: https://dl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub
     dest: /usr/share/keyrings/google-chrome.asc
     mode: '0644'
     force: true
 - name: Add Chrome repository
   apt_repository:
     repo: deb [arch=amd64 signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/google-chrome.asc] https://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main
     state: present
```

At this point I correctly have:

```
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/dl_google_com_linux_chrome_deb.list
```

which correctly contains:

```
deb [arch=amd64 signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/google-chrome.asc] https://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main
```

After calling

```
  - name: Add Chrome package
    apt:
     name: "google-chrome-stable"
```

there is a second list in the sources directory:

```
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/dl_google_com_linux_chrome_deb.list
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list
```

This second list points to the repo, but without the key:

```
### THIS FILE IS AUTOMATICALLY CONFIGURED ###
# You may comment out this entry, but any other modifications may be lost.
deb [arch=amd64] https://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main
```

Like I say, if I remove the second entry, then the package installs correctly.

**Question:** How do I stop this incorrect list from being added?

**Further testing:**
I used Ansible to get the key and add the repo to /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ and then I manually called

```
sudo apt install google-chrome-stable
```

It correctly installed but then also added the google-chrome.list file.

The same thing happens when I try to install **Docker, TeamViewer, VS Code,** and **1Password** so it isn't just Chrome.

So how do I use Ansible to install signed external packages?

Answer (score 1):

I have experienced such behavior a few times when manually installing deb packages. When the deb package is installed, a sources-list file is automatically created.

I can think of a few possibilities you could test:

1. Obviously when chrome is installed, the file `google-chrome.list` is created. You could test if this is overwritten during installation if you **name your file `google-chrome.list`** instead of `dl_google_com_linux_chrome_deb.list`. You have to add the parameter `filename` (without specifying the file extension).

   ```yaml
   - name: Add Chrome repository
     apt_repository:
       repo: deb [arch=amd64 signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/google-chrome.asc] https://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main
       state: present
       filename: google-chrome
   ```

   As long as the existing file is not overwritten, everything should be fine. If it is overwritten again, you could try to run the `apt_repository` command again after the installation.
2. You could **delete the file created by Chrome** after the installation. However, based on the note in the file "any other modifications may be lost.", I don't know if that holds.

   ```yaml
   - name: Remove google-chrome.list file
     file:
       path: /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list
       state: absent
   ```
3. You could **comment out the deb line** in the new file after installation. As it is mentioned there, this modification should then hopefully be preserved.

   ```yaml
   - name: Comment out Chrome's default source.
     lineinfile:
       path: /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list
       regexp: '^(deb .*)$'
       line: '# \g<1>'
       backrefs: yes
   ```

However, you should still test how the behavior is during an update, if the file is overwritten/created again every time. If there is a switch to prevent the creation of the sources-list-file directly during the installation, I don't know.

---

Edit: Combination of solution 1 and 3:

```yaml
- name: Add Chrome repository
  apt_repository:
    repo: deb [arch=amd64 signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/google-chrome.asc] https://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main
    state: present
    filename: google-chrome

- name: Add Chrome package
  apt:
    name: "google-chrome-stable"

- name: Comment out Chrome's default source.
  lineinfile:
    path: /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list
    regexp: '^(deb \[arch=amd64\] .*)$'
    line: '# \g<1>'
    backrefs: yes
```

I have adjusted the `regexp`, so only the deb line without signature key matches.

Comment: Thank you for your comments.
Actually, before I saw your answer, I tried the same as your solution #1.

The sources file then has two entries afterwards, one with the pointer to the key and one without, but at least it seems to work.

Comment: The problem with solution #1 is that although it works, any apt updates create warnings because of the multiple entries.

To get rid of this, I combined solutions #1 and #2 and then there are no warnings, but also the packages will never be updated because there are now no entries in the sources list.

I am thinking that there must be a more elegant way to do this.

Comment: If you combine solution 1 and 2, all sources for Chrome are missing afterwards, that's probably true. Maybe you better combine solution 1 and 3? I have extended my post for this.

Comment: There is actually a very easy way to stop this for Chrome.
If you go to the download web page for the Linux version, there is a pop-up which states:

Note: Installing Google Chrome will add the Google repository so your system will automatically keep Google Chrome up to date. If you don’t want Google's repository, do “sudo touch /etc/default/google-chrome” before installing the package.

Comment: That sounds great. You can do this via the [`file` module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/file_module.html) with the `state: touch` parameter.